# GDB error invalid offset, value too big (0x00000400) Unable to build app in debug mode need help

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an app which was working fine few days ago. But today I'm getting this error:

> {standard input}:1948:invalid offset, value too big (0x00000400)
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit >code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Guys,
After a lot of troubleshooting finally I found the solution. A big Switch Case was the problem. Converting that into if else statement solved the problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a big switch case (in my case it is really big, I generate the function using a script). Compiler bug, perhaps?

Comment: I also had the same problem but it's a huge static array, looks like Xcode can't compile something too big on iPhone. The same code compiles alright on the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today while I was writing an assembly routine for an ARM Cortex-M0 processor. In my case, the code that caused the error looked like this:

```
ldr r7 ,=PRTCNFG_10
```

This is a pseudo instruction causing the processor to load the value of constant PRTCNFG_10 (defined using the .equ directive) into register r7. The pseudo instruction will be translated into

```
ldr r7 ,[pc, #immed8]
```

where #immed8 is an 8 bit immediate value. Since 2^8=256, the definition of PRTCNFG_10 must not be placed beyond pc+256 bytes, otherwise the Assembler will throw an error.

I solved the issue by explicitly allocating PRTCNFG_10 in memory:

```
PRTCNFG_10:
.word 0x606
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw the same issue, which also turned out to be caused by a switch case. It wasn't even that big (26 cases), and it had compiled fine in the past, but for some reason it started to fail today. Replacing it with if-else solved the weird GCC error.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is not strictly about assembler, this question pops up in web searches about this specific errors often enough that I'd like to add an answer that should be helpful to people programming in it.

The assembler syntax is `LDR REG, =SOMETHING`.

If that *SOMETHING* is >16 bits, we got a problem because Thumb doesn't have 32-bit immediates. To fix this, the assembler remembers the constant and replaces the statement with a PC-relative load to something that's less than 0x400 bytes off (more than that doesn't fit in the instruction).

You then say

`.ltoff`

someplace convenient (e.g. right behind the next `bx lr` or `pop {pc}`) to direct the assembler to place these constants *there*.